# Unknown record number while executing SQLite query

Tags: java, sqlite

When I am executing a SQLite query (using sqlite4java) I am following the general scheme of executing it step by step and obtaining one row at a time. My final result should be a 2-D array, whose length should correspond to the amount of records. The problem I am facing is the fact that I don't know in advance how many records are to be returned by my query. so I basically store them in an ArrayList and then copy pointers to the actual array. Is there a technique to somehow obtain the number of records to be returned by the query prior to executing it fully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My final result should be a 2-D array, whose length should correspond to the amount of records.

Why? It would generally be a better idea to make the result a `List<E>` where `E` is some custom type representing "a record".

It sounds like you're already creating an `ArrayList` - so why do you need an actual array? The Collections API is generally more flexible and convenient than using arrays directly.

Comment: for the purpose of further (potential) hardware acceleration which really computes stuff on arrays

Comment: @Bober02: Do you *need* that hardware acceleration at the moment? I suggest you take the simplest approach that works for the moment - and if you *need* to copy the references into an array later on, that's easy enough... and likely to be cheaper than executing a query twice.

Answer (score 0):

No, if using JDBC. You can, however, first do a COUNT() query, and then the real query.